# How to create camera application with specific object detection on android using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, camera, ocr, object-detection

I'd like to create an app that has camera feature and has the ability to detect a specific object. Basically it'll be working like QR-code converter, when the desired object is in front of the camera, then the camera-screen shows a green rectangle or something to inform that the object is correct. When it is incorrect, the app wont be able to capture the image and gives some message that the object is incorrect.

When the object is accepted, then i would like to **convert some text on it to editable-text, and crop some images on specific location (maybe based on X and Y axis of the object).**

I'd like to know, **how or where to start to do that?**

I've been doing some research and i got like OCR (optical character recognition) to convert the text, however i haven't got the one to detect a specific object.

Also, is it possible to edit the UI of the camera app or create our own camera app? because i've seen some android tutorial that the camera app they are using is the native app. (ButtonImage --> native camera app).

FYI: The object is an identification card

Answer (score 0):

I would start with your own app that uses Camera preview.  You can set your own camera preview callback and render the frames on a Surface.

This will allow you to intercept every frame and process it using your routines to try to figure out if it's an object you are interested in.